# Feathersjs: Switching to sockets instead of REST, using Express Middleware with Sockets

Tags: reactjs, authentication, socket.io, feathersjs

So I'm following Feathersjs docs regarding authentication,
and I have a middleware **/signup**,
from [User Management docs](https://docs.feathersjs.com/getting-started/user-management.html):

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    const body = req.body;   
    app.service('users').create({
      email: body.email,
      password: body.password
    })
    // Then redirect to the login page
    .then(user => res.redirect('/login.html'))//this will be a redirect in my client not in the server      
    .catch(next);
  };
};
```

Now in *src/middleware/index.js:* I have :

```
module.exports = function() {
  const app = this;

  app.post('/signup', signup(app));// how can I reimplement this with sockets
  app.use(notFound());
  app.use(logger(app));
  app.use(handler());
};
```

Using REST was easy :

```
request.post(`${SERVER}/signup`)
      .send({ email: username, password: password })
      .then(data=>{console.log(`data comming from response`,data)})
      .catch(error=>{console.log(`ERROR comming from response`,error)})
```

so the problem is that now that I'm using sockets (**feathers-client**) I don't know how to tell feathers client to "post" the email/pass to that **/signup** middleware. Is there any way to achieve this?
this is my client conf:

```
import feathers from 'feathers-client';    
const io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io(SERVER);


let feathersClient = 
  feathers()
    .configure(feathers.socketio(socket))
    .configure(feathers.hooks())
    .configure(feathers.authentication({
      storage: window.localStorage
    }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the signup middleware. Just create a new user through the `/users` service on your client like this:

```
import feathers from 'feathers-client';    
const io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io(SERVER);


let feathersClient = 
  feathers()
    .configure(feathers.socketio(socket))
    .configure(feathers.hooks())
    .configure(feathers.authentication({
      storage: window.localStorage
    }));

feathersClient.service('users').create({
  email: 'test@example.com',
  password: 'testing'
});
```

Then you will be able to authenticate the user like this:

```
feathersClient.authenticate({
  type: 'local',
  email: 'test@example.com',
  password: 'testing'
});
```

Comment: Sorry I was on vacations... I had it like this but I wanted to use the redirect functionality in the logging process, but I was reading that it doesn't work with sockets. thanks @Daff

Comment: Hello @Daff! could you add to your answer how can a middleware be called from socketio connection

Comment: Express middleware can not be accessed on a socket connection. If it has to work on both transports, Feathers hooks should be used.